# Turn off emails only for 404 Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, error-logging, elmah.mvc

I am sharing a simple solution for turning off Elmah sending emails for 404 Http Errors. I wanted elmah to still log the 404 errors in case we find some hackers trying to find some config files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to your Web.config file:

**system.web** node:

```
<httpModules>
    ...
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    ...
</httpModules>
```

**configSections** node:

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="errorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

**elmah** node:

```
<errorFilter>
    <test>
        <and>
            <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
            <regex binding="FilterSourceType.Name" pattern="mail" />
        </and>
    </test>
</errorFilter>
```